# How do I globally make my desktop icons smaller in Ubuntu 16.1?

Tags: gnome, icons, ubuntu-gnome, desktop-icons

I just upgraded to the new Ubuntu Gnome 16.10.  When I restarted, all my icons doubled in size and are off screen at the edges.  I have not been able to find a setting that allows a global resizing of icons.  Is there a way to do this?  I have already manually, individually reduced all the icons on my desktop, but I need a global way to do it.  I am a Linux neophyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Nautilus` (file manager) from `Launcher` (icon is a filing cabinet).

Hover mouse over top screen line and select the `Edit` menu.

Then select `Preferences` -> `Views`. Set the icon size according to the screen below:

[image: Nautilus Icon Size]

If your icon size is > 100% set it to 100%. If it's already 100% then obviously set it less than that.

Comment: @WilliamJ.Dager since this answer solved your problem, you can thank the person who wrote it by "accepting" it (click the grey tick under the score) :)

Comment: Uncertain what "top screen line" means here.